# pstree shows lots of process

Tags: pstree

This is a dump of pstree. I am running firefox (one tab) and gnome-terminal (1 tab).
I count 4 gnome-terminal processes and 34 firefox processes. 
Is it normal? Actually every application running seems to be duplicated.
Thanks

```
init─┬─NetworkManager─┬─dhclient
     │                ├─dnsmasq
     │                └─3*[{NetworkManager}]
     ├─accounts-daemon───2*[{accounts-daemon}]
     ├─acpid
     ├─at-spi-bus-laun─┬─dbus-daemon
     │                 └─3*[{at-spi-bus-laun}]
     ├─at-spi2-registr───{at-spi2-registr}
     ├─atd
     ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
     ├─bamfdaemon───3*[{bamfdaemon}]
     ├─bluetoothd
     ├─colord───{colord}
     ├─console-kit-dae───64*[{console-kit-dae}]
     ├─cron
     ├─cups-browsed
     ├─cupsd───dbus
     ├─2*[dbus-daemon]
     ├─dbus-launch
     ├─dconf-service───2*[{dconf-service}]
     ├─evolution-calen───4*[{evolution-calen}]
     ├─evolution-sourc───2*[{evolution-sourc}]
     ├─firefox───34*[{firefox}]
     ├─gconfd-2
     ├─gdm─┬─gdm-simple-slav─┬─Xorg───2*[{Xorg}]
     │     │                 ├─gdm-session-wor─┬─gnome-session─┬─compiz─┬─sh───+
     │     │                 │                 │               │        └─3*[{c+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─deja-dup-monit+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─evolution-alar+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─gnome-fallback+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─gnome-screensa+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─gnome-settings+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─gnome-user-sha+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─polkit-gnome-a+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─ssh-agent
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─telepathy-indi+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─tracker-miner-+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─tracker-store─+++
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─update-notifie+
     │     │                 │                 │               ├─zeitgeist-data+
     │     │                 │                 │               └─3*[{gnome-sess+
     │     │                 │                 └─2*[{gdm-session-wor}]
     │     │                 └─2*[{gdm-simple-slav}]
     │     └─2*[{gdm}]
     ├─5*[getty]
     ├─gnome-keyring-d───7*[{gnome-keyring-d}]
     ├─gnome-terminal─┬─gnome-pty-helpe
     │                ├─tcsh───pstree
     │                └─3*[{gnome-terminal}]
     ├─goa-daemon───2*[{goa-daemon}]
     ├─gvfs-afc-volume───2*[{gvfs-afc-volume}]
     ├─gvfs-gphoto2-vo───{gvfs-gphoto2-vo}
     ├─gvfs-mtp-volume───{gvfs-mtp-volume}
     ├─gvfs-udisks2-vo───{gvfs-udisks2-vo}
     ├─gvfsd───{gvfsd}
     ├─gvfsd-burn───{gvfsd-burn}
     ├─gvfsd-fuse───4*[{gvfsd-fuse}]
     ├─gvfsd-trash───2*[{gvfsd-trash}]
     ├─hud-service───3*[{hud-service}]
     ├─indicator-appli───{indicator-appli}
     ├─indicator-bluet───2*[{indicator-bluet}]
     ├─indicator-datet───3*[{indicator-datet}]
     ├─indicator-messa───2*[{indicator-messa}]
     ├─indicator-print───2*[{indicator-print}]
     ├─indicator-sessi───2*[{indicator-sessi}]
     ├─indicator-sound───2*[{indicator-sound}]
     ├─indicator-sync-───{indicator-sync-}
     ├─irqbalance
     ├─login───tcsh
     ├─mission-control───2*[{mission-control}]
     ├─modem-manager
     ├─polkitd───{polkitd}
     ├─pulseaudio─┬─gconf-helper
     │            └─2*[{pulseaudio}]
     ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─rtkit-daemon───2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
     ├─ubuntuone-syncd───3*[{ubuntuone-syncd}]
     ├─udevd───2*[udevd]
     ├─udisksd───4*[{udisksd}]
     ├─unity-applicati───2*[{unity-applicati}]
     ├─unity-files-dae───2*[{unity-files-dae}]
     ├─unity-lens-frie───2*[{unity-lens-frie}]
     ├─unity-lens-phot───3*[{unity-lens-phot}]
     ├─unity-music-dae───{unity-music-dae}
     ├─unity-musicstor───2*[{unity-musicstor}]
     ├─unity-panel-ser───3*[{unity-panel-ser}]
     ├─unity-scope-gdr───3*[{unity-scope-gdr}]
     ├─unity-scope-vid───2*[{unity-scope-vid}]
     ├─unity-video-len───{unity-video-len}
     ├─unity-webapps-s───2*[{unity-webapps-s}]
     ├─upowerd───2*[{upowerd}]
     ├─upstart-file-br
     ├─upstart-socket-
     ├─upstart-udev-br
     ├─vsftpd
     ├─whoopsie───2*[{whoopsie}]
     ├─wpa_supplicant
     ├─zeitgeist-daemo───{zeitgeist-daemo}
     └─zeitgeist-fts─┬─cat
                     └─{zeitgeist-fts}
```

Comment: Questions about Ubuntu 13.04 are considered as offtopic,because Ubuntu 13.04 already reached EOL.

Comment: @giuper edited your Q to remove version specification..

Comment: Firefox default limit 50 instances in total. Changing the value of browser.sessionhistory.max_entries may help.

Answer (score 3):

Those are threads. If you read `man pstree` you will see the following part:

> Child threads of a process are found under the parent process  and  are
>          shown with the process name in curly braces, e.g.

```
       icecast2---13*[{icecast2}]
```

Which is comparable with what you see:

```
       firefox───34*[{firefox}]
```

So, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is normal. A lot of programs use more than one process, therefore there is nothing to worry about.

The reason for this is programs like Google Chrome/Chromium or I.E. divide the programs functions such as rendering individual tabs into multiple processes to increase the efficiency of use across multiple processor cores and threads allowing for better performance.

Other programs do this as well do delegate program tasks across multiple processor cores or threads if the program has the possibility of causing too much strain on a single thread/core.

Source:http://www.liutilities.com/articles/what-are-computer-processes/#.UwaXgvldV1Y
http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/getting_started/s1_procs.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does provide kind-of answer, but it's very low quality. You should explain why that happens, and probably additionally link to some source.

Comment: I attempted to improve the answer by further elaboration. Sorry for the short answer.